# How can I put an element to right of a centered element?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have two inputs ("email" and "password") centered horizontally. Now, I want to put an item to right of them, but keeping them (email and password) centered.

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    <div className="col-md-6 row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <input placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <input placeholder="password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button text="Entrar" />
</div>
```

If I remove `<button>`, inputs are centered when I put the button all three items are centered, but I just want center `email` and `password` inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would just be to give the element you want on the right `position: absolute` (to take it out of the flow) and then use `left` and `top` to position it where you want it (noting that these values can be percentage-based). This means you may have to play around with values to get it exactly where you want it, but will keep the other element in the vertical center:

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style='display: flex; justify-content: center;'>
  <div class="col-md-6 row" style='background-color: yellow;'>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input placeholder="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input placeholder="password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Entrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Is there any more responsive way?

Comment: As far as I am aware, absolute-positioning is the best way of handling this. Unfortunately, Bootstrap is basically built around evenly-positioned elements, so doesn't really play nicely when you want to break its 'flow'. You're still able to add `media queries` though; simply adjust the `left` and `top` values (or make use of `right`) to have a little extra responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks! I will use media queries since I need a mobile friendly version

Answer (score 0):

I would change a bit your code.
This answer asumes that you want the  bellow the fields and right aligned.

Like this.

```
 <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
 <div className="col-md-6 row">
     <div className="col-md-6">
         <input placeholder="email" />
     </div>
     <div className="col-md-6">
         <input placeholder="password" />
     </div>
 </div>
 <div className="col-md-6 row">
     <button class="pull-right" text="Entrar" />
 </div>
```